# Rails Functional Test assert_select finds nothing after AJAX post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, assert, xmlhttprequest

On Rails 2.3.2 I'm trying to test a view in a functional test

```
def test_view
 get :form
 xhr :post, :add_to_cart, {:id => 1}
 post :create, {:param => value}
 assert_select 'title', 'Success!'
end
```

But keep getting a failure:

Expected at least 1 element matching "title", found 0.
 is not true.

I understand that you cannot use 'assert_select' after a xhr call, but in this case, I'm doing it AFTER a regular post request.

If I drop the xhr request

```
def test_view
 get :form
 post :create, {:param => value}
 assert_select 'title', 'Success!'
end
```

Then it works like charm.
I could set the cart (which I store in session) manually, but then I would not be really testing the view...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've already figured it out -- functional tests expect a single controller action, not multiple actions. I'd suggest replacing this with an [integration test](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/IntegrationTest).

Comment: You can test as many actions as you want with functional tests. This makes sense if you want to check if an action was successfull, ie post :update, get :show, format: :json

Answer (score 0):

If you make an xhr request then `@response.content_type == 'text/javascript'` and `assert_select` won't work with it. To get it to work you have to change the content type to `'text/html'`, like so:

```
xhr(:get, something)
@response.content_type = 'text/html'
assert_select 'title', 'Success!'
```

Comment: If this still works, I wonder why. When I look at the text coming back, it isn't HTML, but rather JavaScript with HTML inside a giant string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As noted above, it comes from ActionController setting the `content-type` to `text-javascript`, while `assert_select` works with `text/html`. The better way to set it though is not to mingle with `@response` in the test, but in the controller, like this:

```
respond_to do |format| 
  format.html {...}
end
```

This will force content type to `text/html`.